# Change fontstyle on multiple headings - using only Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change fontstyle on multiple headings - using only Javascript.

```
  function smurfa() {
        document.body.innerHTML = 
        document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Katt/g,'Smurf');
        document.body.innerHTML = 
        document.body.innerHTML.replace(/katt/g,'smurf');
        alert("YOU GOT SMURFED!");
        document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3').forEach(function(tag) {
        tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
        tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML.fontcolor("red");

        }); 
    }
```

Comment: You should use CSS.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to i change the fontstyle on the headings using only Javascript?
I am a total noob.

Comment: I suspect to be a spam user.

Comment: Learn about the `style` property.

Comment: tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML.fontStyle("italic"); ?
Doesn't work.. :(

Comment: because innerHTML does NOT have methods. It is just a string.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: But im able to change fontcolor. Shouldn't i be able to change fontstyle too doing something similar? 
tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML.fontcolor("red");  <<

Doing something similar?

Comment: You can not change the fontcolor like that. Look at `style` like the link I posted explains it. `tag.style.color = "lime"`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use css for styling, but if you want to do it that way

```
const headers = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3")
headers.forEach(x => x.style.fontStyle = 'italic');
```